# I'm making a particle sandbox sand falling system in c++ sfml but I'm having some major performance issues

Tags: c++, sfml, particle-system

```
// spawn
    if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Q)) // coal
    {
        
        particleR = new RectangleShape;
        particleV.push_back(*particleR);
        particleV[particleV.size() - 1].setSize(Vector2f(1, 1));
        particleV[particleV.size() - 1].setFillColor(Color(55, 55, 55));
        particleV[particleV.size() - 1].setPosition(Vector2f(worldPosI));
        parID.push_back(1);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < particleV.size(); i++)
    {
        if (parID[i] == 1) // checks if its coal
        {
            if (particleV[i].getPosition().y < 10) // checks if the particle is in air
            {
                particleV[i].move(0, 1); 
                for (int q = 0; q < particleV.size(); q++) // goes through each particle with each other and checks if some particle is inside 
                {
                    if (particleV[i].getPosition().x == particleV[q].getPosition().x && particleV[i].getPosition().y == particleV[q].getPosition().y && i != q)
                    {
                        particleV[i].move(0, -1); // if a particle is inside other particle, go up.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that, these for loops can not handle going through thousands of particles every frame and checking of they are colliding with each other. I wonder if there is a better another way of checking the interactions between particles.

Comment: For starters, `int q = i` would be good. No need to check collision multiple times between the same pair of particles.

Comment: One usual approach is to put your particles into a spatial acceleration structure (Octree, BVH etc.). This approach allows you to find only a few candidate particles for which you need to compute possible interactions.

Comment: replacing ```int q = 0``` with ```int q = i``` causes the particles to not fall